# How do I get back to the prison after killing the cockatrice?

Tags: the-witcher, the-witcher-series

So in Chapter 2 of The Witcher (Enhanced Edition), right at the start, I have woken up in Vizima's prison and all my stuff is gone (of course). The guards let prisoners earn back their freedom (and belongings) if they go and kill the cockatrice that is roaming the sewers, which I do and now I have its head to present as evidence. I then emerge to the surface.
I can go back into the sewers from here, but how do I get back to the prison? I have searched the sewers maybe 3 times now and I can't find any entrance to it. Should I maybe look somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter prison from surface. Entrance is before gates to the Trade Quarter on the south-east side of the map, past Thaler place, opposite to the gates to St. Lebioda's backyard.